# Can't import class from jar file although it's visible among IntelliJ External Libraries

Tags: java, runtime-packages

Like [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/85isf.jpg)  shows. I have project party-management that uses common-lending-lib. common-lending-lib then uses math2 library.

When I open common-lending-lib project, it can easily detect math2 dependency and use it.
When I open party-management-project, it can detect common-lending-lib, and math2, but during **runtime**, it fails on functionality that common-lending-lib takes from math2.

What can be the reason? These projects are in Spring Boot, if it matters at all. I use IntelliJ 2017.1.5 and Java 1.8

Can package name be the reason? I have:

- party management in org.kd package
- common lending lib in org.kd package
- math2 in org.kd.math package

Details of the project can be found on https://github.com/LendingBusiness

Comment: I tried to rename the package, so that now all classes are in org.kd, but it had no effect

Comment: NoClassDefFoundError can also arise because of class version incompatibility. Have you checked that you are not ending up with 2 version of the class on the runtime classpath? Also, are you sure that the class being packaged is the one you expect?